# Отправлять разный текст через Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Суть проблемы: хочу поделиться текстом из своего приложения в другие (напр. почта или заметки)
отправляю `Intent.ACTION_SEND, type = "text/plain"`

Можно ли в зависмости от выбранного приложения отправлять разный текст через Intent, отследить по имени пакета, к примеру.

Нужно это потому что почтовое приложение хуавея плохо обрабатывает ссылки, которые присылаю простым текстом, поэтому приходится отправлять так:

```
putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<a href=\"www.google.com\"/>Google</a>")
```

А заметки на хуавее прекрасно понимают строку `www.google.com` как ссылку без тега `a href`

Comment: нельзя, но вы можете заранее посмотреть есть ли у юзера определенное приложение и уже от этого отталкиваться какой текст ему предоставить

Comment: @Tiarait спасибо за инфо